# custom directory listing handler in ruby for nginx

Tags: ruby, nginx, sinatra, directory-listing

I just found [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/160327/get-nginx-to-always-load-webdir-page-php-on-directories-if-no-index-html-page) on serverfault which details how to create a custom directory listing handler for nginx with a php script. I would like to do the same thing but with a ruby script.

```
location /test/ {
  error_page 404 = /webdir/handler.php;
  return 404;
}
```

My question is, would I simply do the same thing but reference the `handler.rb` instead of `handler.php`, I mean, will nginx automatically know to evaluate the ruby script's and output to the user's browser? So do I simply create a script that does some `puts` calls, or what is the preferred way of doing this? I don't know much about rack or sinatra, but is this a situation in which either would come in handy? I do have passenger installed.

I would most likely want to include css in this to make the listing look nice, and I would possibly prefer to create the structure in haml or erb. I don't mind if the structure template and css would need to be inline in the same `handler.rb`, though if it's possible to separate it out into files that would be beautiful.

Finally, I would like this to apply to the `mysite.com/downloads/` directory as well as all of its sub-directories. What would be the preferred `location` directive? I saw that

```
location ~ /$
```

is to make it work on all directories, but I only want it to apply to `downloads/` and any of its subdirectories. I think it'd be a simple regex modification but I'd rather be sure.

Thanks, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, nginx will not automatically evaluate Ruby scripts. Your best bet is to set up a handler as a Rack application of some sort (pretty much all Ruby web frameworks or handlers are Rack applications these days, including Sinatra and Rails) and then use passenger or a Ruby server like unicorn set up as an nginx proxy.

Given your additional requirements, I would start by looking at Sinatra.

Comment: I do have passenger, and even then it won't evaluate ruby scripts right. So I should look into sinatra. Would you happen to have any further advice?

Comment: Specifically, would you be kind enough to provide more information regarding the nginx setup? So I would make it a sinatra app, and then? My confusion is how I would set it up as the handler for directory listings, it seems to me from what you said that it wouldn't be the same as the above.

Comment: A simple google query ("sinatra nginx passenger") gave me http://blog.zerosum.org/2008/7/4/passenger-3-sinatra and a number of other resources. Do try to DAFS every once in a while.

Comment: Of course I searched, one comes to stackoverflow for personal expertise and I figured since you had the courtesy of responding to this question, perhaps you'd have some personal experience with regards to this. Also, given the link you pasted, I don't see how you could determine that it holds any relevance to your example query. I don't think my question merited your tone.

Comment: When DAFS is appropriate, I will tell people to DAFS. There's a wealth of information on building and configuring Rack applications on a variety of platforms literally at your fingertips. Ok -- figuratively at your fingertips.